# Transform Data Objects to View Objects for different views with the same formatting

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm developing a web application, which collects data from different sources (web services, EJBs, etc.) and displays them in the browser and in a PDF.

Currently I call all the external services and create my own POJOs. Basically I transform the external objects to my own representation (and only take the properties I need).

The data has then to be formatted for the web view (browser) and the PDF. For example some texts have to be "abbreviated", which means they have to be cut off and ellipsis are added (...). The formatting has to be identical for the web (HTML) and the PDF.

My question now is where should I put the formatting logic.

- If I add view specific properties to my POJOs, which hold the formatted texts, I mix view logic with the data. If I then maybe later have a third view where I need a different formatting I have to pollute the POJOs even more.
- If I send the POJOs directly to the views (web and PDF), then the views have to do the formatting and I might copy the formatting logic in two places (e.g. once implemented in JSP and once in XSLT).

Should I create another layer, which transforms/maps the POJOS to "view" specific POJOs, which are prepared for the view?

Let's say I have an object Customer, which holds the properties firstName and lastName. The view is limited to only show 5 characters and always shows "firstName  lastName" (for the HTML view and the PDF)

Should I create a CustomerView, which has the property "name" and only holds a substring with 5 characters length?

Then I could have a CustomerTransformer, which would have the Customer object as the input and the CustomerView object as the output.

Would that be a reasonable solution? How would I call these objects? Does the extension "View" make the purpose clear?

**Is there a default way to handle this situation?**

Thanks for your input, hints or suggestions

Comment: Did you know that `MVC` has three letters? The code knowing both `M` and `V` belongs to the `C`.